# Disable prompt when opening a CSV file in LibreOffice/OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice, csv, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice

Every time I open a CSV file, LibreOffice presents me with a prompt asking to confirm Character Set, Language, and Separator options (tab, comma, semicolon etc). This prompt is not present in Microsoft Office, and I find it unnecessary, because all my CSV files are just that--comma-separated value files. The time wasted on addressing this prompt as I open dozens of CSV files every time, and I get a prompt every single time.

Comment: If all your files follow the same format, this is indeed cumbersome. Yet, there is a good reason why it asks this, and i find it bad design that Excel doesn't. Aside from the separator, your files also need to be consistent in terms of encoding and encapsulation. More on this over here: https://theonemanitdepartment.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/the-absolute-minimum-everyone-working-with-data-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-file-types-encoding-delimiters-and-data-types-no-excuses/